# how to read xml file in IDQ

Tags: informatica, data-quality

I have a requirement to read XML file in IDQ. I am new to idq and not sure how to read xml file as there is no direct transformation available like informatica power center. 
could anyone please explain in brief how to achieve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since there is no XML parser transformation as equivalence to Power Center

Answer (score 0):

**No, IDQ can not read XML data sources**

If you have PowerCenter you can integrate your DQ mapping and pass the XML data to the IDQ mapplet but to process a XML source it will need some intermediate step to read the data prior to processing in IDQ.